# Нужен подходящий плагин для wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Пример того что должно быть [ссылка](https://www.consumeraffairs.com/dating_services/)

Задача: В категории(рубрике) будут посты(записи), у постов должен быть рейтинг, рейтинг должны проставлять коментирующие пост, то есть в форме для коментирования должен появиться виджет оценки, человек пишет имя, мыло, сообщение и выбирает оценку, отправляет, его коментарий публикуется, и у коментария должна показываться оценка которую он поставил, ну и оценка поста соответственно считается на основе оценок в коментариях к нему.

Comment: Так вроде WP-PostRatings удовлетворяет всем требованиям https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/

Comment: @KAGGDesign нет, там схема оценки другая, там просто виджет у поста, со звездами, то есть можно не оставляя комента оценить запись, а нужно чтобы именно напротив коментария была оценка к посту